# convert string to date format using javascript angulajrs

Tags: javascript, angular

Here is my string
13-12-2017 05:05 AM

Need to convert with (that my expectation)
Date 2017-12-13T05:05:00.000Z

Tried

```
var mydate = '13-12-2017 05:05 AM';
var selectedDate = new Date(mydate);
```

console.log(selectedDate);
//Invalid date format

Comment: you could use a library like [moments](https://momentjs.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var mydate = '2017-12-13 05:05 AM';
var selectedDate = new Date(mydate);
console.log(moment(selectedDate).format( ));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to rewrite mydate using this format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm

in your case:

```
var mydate = '2017-12-13 05:05 AM';
```